# VideoView stop playing video

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have created an app for Android 4.0.3 (Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1")
The app play an mp4 video file all the time in full screen mode.
When the video stop(finish), the app start it again from the beginning.

Now the problem is that after 15 minutes I got an error like  **"cannot play this video"**

So I compiled the same app for Android 2.0.3 for my HTC Desire Z and works great, without any problem.

So please help me to figure out where is the problem here?

Comment: This problem u are facing on real device or on emuilator?